Add custom fonts to excel generator in flutter
How to add custom fonts to excel generator in flutter. https://pub.dev/packages/excel . We want to create excel file with japanese font "ＭＳ Ｐゴシック" . Is there any chance to add ttf file externally and apply to excel file?
I have added .ttf file in asset folder and applied to the excel file generator . But font did not reflect in the excel file. only inbuilt fonts of that package only applying to excel file, I want to add external fonts "ＭＳ Ｐゴシック" to the file

Currently, the excel package in Flutter does not natively support embedding custom fonts, such as “ＭＳ Ｐゴシック,” into an Excel file. The package only works with the built-in fonts, and it lacks the functionality for specifying external fonts or embedding .ttf files directly in the generated Excel file.
However, you can consider a few alternative approaches to achieve this, like

Use Post-Processing in Excel
Use an External Library that Supports Custom Fonts
Apply Font Styles with Excel Macros
HTML to Excel Conversion


I found the solution to add custom font in the flutter excel generator by using "syncfusion_flutter_xlsio" sdk.
I have added the sample code for the reference
pubspeck.yaml file
 fonts:
- family: ＭＳ Ｐゴシック
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/font/MSPGothic.ttf

import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_xlsio/xlsio.dart' as xlsio;
generateXLSX() async {
final xlsio.Workbook workbook = xlsio.Workbook();
final xlsio.Worksheet sheet = workbook.worksheets[0];
sheet.enableSheetCalculations();

// Set the custom font
final xlsio.Style style = workbook.styles.add('customFontStyle');
style.fontName = "ＭＳ Ｐゴシック";
style.fontSize = 12;

// Apply style to a cell
  
  sheet.getRangeByIndex(1, 1).cellStyle = style;
  sheet.getRangeByIndex(1, 1).setText("益田市");


// Save the file
final List<int> bytes = workbook.saveAsStream();

final Uint8List data = Uint8List.fromList(bytes);

var value = await FileSaver.instance.saveFile(
  name: 'fileName.xlsx',
  bytes: data,
);

workbook.dispose();

}

Please use the correct code formatting in your answer. To see how look at Markdown help
